# jedi code library installer cannot find Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jedi

I migrated all my components from one pc to another. On the old pc the Jedi JCL installer will correctly detect a Delphi XE2 installation and will show its tab, but on the new pc it does not (it only recognizes a Delphi 7 installation). Notice that on the new pc when I run the jcl install.bat it will use the Delphi XE2 compiler to create the installer exe.
What step can I do to have this sorted out?

The version of Jedi is the latest one at the moment that is 3.47

Comment: Did you run XE2 IDE under the user account you want to install JCL ?
Did he path to XE2 binaries has spaces or non-latin characters in it ? PS. XE2 updates installed ?

If anything, you can open JCL installer from within the IDE and debug it like you debug any other application. `d:\DelphiProjects\Libs\JCL\jcl\install\JediInstaller.dpr` Or at least you can track what instalelr does in `SysInternals Process Monitor` and see which register paths and file paths are tried to detect XE2 to maybe see where some search fails.

Comment: "jedi component library" there aint such a thing and never was So what do you actually installing, JEDI *CODE* Library or JEDI *VCL* ??? May it be that you try to install JediVCL without having JEDI CodeLib installed ?

Comment: @Arioch It's the JCL (Jedi code) installation I am referring here. The JVCL cannot start because the JCL cannot install.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by SysInternals Process Monitor?

Comment: "Process Monitor" program by "SysInternals.com" team. You ca n google those three words if you like. // also you still did not answered my first questions

Comment: the user account is same, the installation path is the default one, so of course there are spaces for example "Rad Studio" has a space, and there are no non-latin characters,but how does this affect the JCL? I am now trying to repair my DXE2 installation as I see that there are problems with it

Comment: about spaces - JCL installer had troubles with finding RSVARS and DCC32 if there were spaces. I remember the fix was trivial and should be in main branch now, but who knows. // about non-Latin, for some locales like Russian and some other, Windows uses different charsets for graphic and console(text-mode) applications. Since the installer is graphic app and calls text-mode CLI apps, it may result in problems. And there is no good obvious generic solution to it. Try to run the installer from the IDe as a regular app and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by reinstalling Delphi XE2 (Full installation with registry). The problem was that I had copied the registry keys from my other pc into the new pc. The problematic key was the library key. For some reason the JCL installer did not like the paths in the library, most probably could not find the paths it expected.

Comment: you could use Process Monitors to see which keys and paths were tried and failed. That is a good tool that can help you to solve many problems when programs fail to meet expectation. I suggest you to add ti to your toolbox